# К каким объектам можно применять moveToThread

Tags: c++, qt

Допустимо ли применять moveToThread к объекту, созданному на стеке? Например, так:

```
QThread *thread_ptr = new QThread;
MyClass obj;
obj.moveToThread(thread_ptr);
// (&obj)->moveToThread(thread_ptr);
```

Не возникнет ли тут проблема, связанная с тем, что локальный объект расположен в памяти, которую в общем-то переместить невозможно, а также она будет очищена при выходе из области видимости? Или же moveToThread произведёт глубокое копирование объекта в память указанного потока?

Comment: Вангую что нет, хотя бы потому что в QObject конструкторы копирования операторы присваивания удалены, что как бэ намекает

Comment: Плюс в документации явно написано, что нельзя перемещать объекты с родителем, видимо как раз потому-что при удалении родителя пемещаемый в другой поток объект тоже будет удалён как child. А в описываемой вами ситуации будет похожее поведение - при выходе из области видимости объект будет удалён, при том что он уже в другом потоке и в другой очереди событий

Comment: А ещё можно посмотреть исходники moveToThread: [https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp.html#_ZN7QObject12moveToThreadEP7QThread](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp.html#_ZN7QObject12moveToThreadEP7QThread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moveToThread` ничего никуда не перемещает, вопреки своему имени. Он устанавливает ассоциированный с объектом поток. Т.е. устанавливает поток, который будет обрабатывать все слоты, которые должны быть вызваны для этого объекта в случае `QueuedConnection`. Совершенно не важно где создан Ваш объект, на стеке или в куче. Перемещение его в другой поток с этим никак не связано.

Answer (score 2):

С большой вероятностью получите проблему. Никто не будет копировать за Вас. Поэтому, обычно в Qt все передают по указателю (или умному, но это реже) и почти всегда создают в динамической памяти.

Почему же "с большой вероятностью"? может так повезти, что объект будет как то жив/доступен, когда к нему обратятся.

Comment: Не будет там никаких проблем, никакого перемещения объекта не происходит.

Comment: так никто же и не говорил, что перемещения будут. А вот проблемы будут. Но... пусть для Вас это будет приятным сюрпризом.